# Use awk to query a remote page directly in OSX

Tags: macos, bash, awk

I have a script to automatically connect and renew authentication on a Cisco router's captive portal. It's working and looks like this:

```
 while true
 do
    export ssid=$(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I | awk '/ SSID/ {print substr($0, index($0, $2))}')
    if [ "$ssid" != "SSID_NAME" ]; then # Not SSID_NAME
        sleep 10
    else # SSID_NAME Connected
        if ping -c 1 google.com; then # Connected and everything is OK
            sleep 5
        else # There is no ping
            curl -O http://auth.address/login.html
            var=$(awk -F\" '/au_pxytimetag/{print $(NF-1)}' login.html)
            curl -d "uname=guest&pwd=password&au_pxytimetag=$var" http://auth.address/login.html
        fi
    fi
 done
```

However I'd like not to store the login.html page and get the variable value directly, but when i use

```
 var=$(awk -F\" '/au_pxytimetag/{print $(NF-1)}' http://auth.address/login.html)
```

I get in terminal

```
  awk: can't open file http://auth.address/login.html
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` is not capable of getting the webpage, if you do not want to store the `login.html` you can redirect the output of `curl` to `awk` directly like this:

```
var=$(curl http://auth.address/login.html | awk -F\" '/au_pxytimetag/{print $(NF-1)}')
```